# Excel VBA cross-sheet referencing

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first attempt at using VB in excel so bear with me.

I have a column of names where there are multiple duplicates of each, then in another column is the hours that each person as spent on a particular project. What my function does is goes down the list of names and each time it finds a match with $name it adds the corresponding hours up then returns the total.

Now this works when the table I'm getting the input from is on the same sheet as I'm using the Function, however I want to have the results on a separate sheet from the table. I believe its an issue with how its referencing the cell in line 10 but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

```
Function Hours(start as Range, finish As Range, name As String) As Double

Hours = 0#
RowStart = start.Row
RowFinish = finish.Row
NameColumn = start.Column
HourColumn = finish.Column

For i = RowStart To RowFinish
    If Cells(i, NameColumn) = name Then Hours = Hours + Cells(i, HourColumn).Value
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: As a general rule you cannot use a UDF called *from the worksheet* to manipulate any other cells on the worksheet, nor other worksheets.

Comment: But in this case, can't you just call the function from the *other* sheet (the one where you want the output to appear), passing in the ranges on the Table sheet?  I think that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David pointed out, pass in the range from the other sheet and manipulate the data from there. See following UDF.

```
Function GetTotalHours(EmpNameR As Range, EmpName As String) As Double

    Dim CellR As Range, HoursTotal As Double
    HoursTotal = 0
    For Each CellR In EmpNameR
        If CellR.Value = EmpName Then
            HoursTotal = HoursTotal + CellR.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next

    GetTotalHours = HoursTotal

End Function
```

In action:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I feel this is the best answer, but of course it assumes that hours is in the very next column from names.

Comment: True, but that's just a matter of adjusting the column offset in the `.Offset` part. Not so hard to understand, and can even be manipulated by using any combination of `Match` or what-have-you locators relative to the column where the employee names are found.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! I actually have and hour column for each month so I'll need to adjust how the offset works but that's not a problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Remember, though, that UDF pound-for-pound will lose to formulas in terms of sheer speed when they attempt to do the same thing (something about UDFs being coded in VBA and formulas in raw C++). This is why I also placed a `SUMIF` comparison up there in any case it should fit your needs. However, a UDF is easier to manipulate if you have the experience. In any case, good luck.

Comment: Ok, one more kinda-related question, is there a way to reference the cell that is using the formula? Like a this.Cell type of thing? I can't see to find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can access any sheet by index of by name, I always prefer by name.

```
Sheets("my_output_sheet_name").cells(row#, col#).value = total_hours
```

WHen you do "Cells(i, NameColumn)" it is assuming the current/active sheet. Doing what i said above, allows you to access any sheet regardless of which one is active.

So assuming you want to also list the names in the results sheet, right after the for loop, you could do:

```
Sheets("results").Cells(resultRow, NameColumn).value = name 
Sheets("results").Cells(resultRow, HourColumn).value = Hours
```

where obviously you have a sheet called "results" and you will increment "resultsRow" after every name.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this does not answer your VBA question, but there is a much easier way to do this within Excel without VBA. Try:

`=SUMPRODUCT((NameColumn="Name")*Hours)`

The forumula works by testing each name in `NameColumn` (a named range- you can replace it with the address of your data) with "Name" which results in an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. When that array is multiplied by `Hours` range (also a named range), `TRUE` values are converted to 1s, and `FALSE` values are 0s. Then `SUMPRODUCT()` adds the result.